# Nested descendants not found Linq XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to receive all elements with a given tag name, no matter where they are.
I have used the `Descendants()` method on my base element like this:

```
public static XElement GetModifiedDataSource(XElement rechnung, string parentElement, string newElementTag, string value = null)
{
    foreach (var element in rechnung.Descendants(parentElement))
    {
        XElement newElement = new XElement(newElementTag);
        if (value != null)
        {
            newElement.SetValue(value);
        }
        element.Add(newElement);
    }
    return rechnung;
}
```

For examlpe with `string parentElement = "Produkt"` I should receive multiple.
Sample:

```
<Schlussrechnung xmlns="http://someurl">
    <Parameter>
      <Version></Version>
    </Parameter>
    <Uebersicht>
      <Kopf>
        <Rechnungsempfaenger>
        </Rechnungsempfaenger>
      </Kopf>
      <Detail>
      </Detail>
    </Uebersicht>
    <AbrechnungsDetail>
      <Messpunkt>
        <Produktgruppe>
          <Produkt>
            HERE
          </Produkt>
          <Produkt>
            AND HERE
          </Produkt>
        </Produktgruppe>
      </Messpunkt>
  </Schlussrechnung>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code.  If you need all the elements with the same tag use following : List<XElement> produkts 
 = rechnung.Descendants("Produkt").ToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to accomplish this :

1. Get all descendant elements in the element under rechnung XElement like

   `var descendants = rechnung.Descendants()`.
2. Get all Descendants with "LocalName" = "Produkt" using linq like

   `var getAllProdukt = descendants.ToList().Where(desc => desc.Name.LocalName == "Produkt").ToList();`

This way you get a List of XElements with the tag "Produkt"

Comment: What if I wanted to specifly search for one of the tags with a URI?

Answer (score 1):

Your XML has *default namespace* which your target element inherits from the root element:

```
xmlns="http://someurl"
```

You can use combination of `XNamespace` and element's local-name to reference element in namespace:

```
// you can make `ns` as additional parameter of `GetModifiedDataSource`
XNamespace ns = "http://someurl"; 
foreach (var element in rechnung.Descendants(ns+parentElement))
{
    ....
}
```

Or, with the risk of getting element from the wrong namespace if any, you can ignore the namespace by looking only at the element's local-name:

```
foreach (var element in rechnung.Descendants().Where(o => o.Name.LocalName == parentElement)
{
    ....
}
```